# DQL Concat many strings

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder, dql

I want to concat many strings with DQL but I have an error message when I try.

My code:

```
$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('u')
   ->from(Tutore::class, 'u')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->concat($qb->expr()->concat('u.nom', $qb->expr()->literal(' ')), 'u.prenom'), ':fullname')
   ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('u.ancien', 0))
   ->setParameter('fullname', $fullname);

return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

The error message :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 77: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'AND'" at /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 54
```

I also tried by replacing this :

```
$qb->expr()->literal(' '))
```

By a simple : " ".

Comment: The first clause should be with where, not andWhere

Comment: Actually, you can use where and andWhere without any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple:

```
->andWhere("concat(u.nom, ' ', u.prenom) = :fullname")
.............................................................................
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it with doctrine expr functions ?

Comment: I think this way is not bad. Is it query work for you?